# Excel VBA can I have a pick list or drop down list that isn't a form?

Tags: excel, vba, list

My VBA code creates an array from the sheetnames in my workbook. I need the code to pop up a pick list so the user can select a worksheet. I don't want to create a form because I will be copying the script into many workbooks as I get them and I don't want to have to take the time to create a form in each one.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
Dim ItemFromFile As String
Dim ImportWb As Workbook, ImportWs As Worksheet
Dim i As Single, Tabs As Integer

    ItemFromFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files, *.xls*", , "Select the File & Import Range")
    
    'If ItemFromFile Then
        Set ImportWb = Workbooks.Open(ItemFromFile, , True)
        
        Tabs = ImportWb.Sheets.Count
        ReDim TabList(1 To Tabs)
        
        For i = 1 To Tabs
            TabList(n) = ImportWb.Sheets(n).Name
        Next i
        
        'some code here to display a pick list and allow user to select a worksheet.

        MsgBox ("The choice made on the ListBox was: " & listChoice)
        
    'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you could create the form in one book, then just write a sub to open that book, use the userform, get the info then close the book again.

Comment: Or, you could get the user to make the selection in a "Data Validation" drop down on your worksheet, then run the sub.

Comment: How long is the list? if it's short you could do it with an input box and select by number